# change \FOR to \FOREACH in program package

Tags: algorithms, program

In the `program` package, is it possible to introduce new keyword `\FOREACH` which behaves exactly like `\FOR` but writes *foreach* instead of *for* on the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `program` package already defines a `\FOREACH` command which is slightly different from the `\FOR` command in its formatting.  You can add the following to your preamble after loading the `program` package to redefine `\FOREACH` to format things like `\FOR`.

```
\makeatletter
\def\FOREACH{\keyword{foreach}\ \tab
 \gdef\DO{\@marginspace\keyword{do}\ \global\let\DO=\@oldDO}}
\makeatother
```